# Can I use two CMS Magento and WordPress in One Site

Tags: magento-1.9, wordpress

Can  I use two CMS Magento and WordPress in One Site
I want to crate a site in Magento But i want to write this blog on Wordpress and i just want to connect wordpress to Magento. is there any way to this please let me know. Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can with http://fishpig.co.uk/magento/wordpress-integration/

Wordpress is not really considered as a save system though (let's say a least, Magento is saver). There is a lot of paid and unpaid blogging extension around as well.

If you still want to go this way, be aware of some things:

Fishpig will fill feed the wordpress articles to Magento. Not every plugin will be respected there. For some plugins, paid extension to make them work are offered.

Use Wordpress in an **extra Database**. This will make the whole thing a lot saver.

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can, use this module http://fishpig.co.uk/magento/wordpress-integration/